# PowerShell date format not behaving

Tags: string, powershell, datetime

I'm stumped. :)

My computer has PowerShell 5.1 installed. On another computer (same language) 5.0 it works as expected. (Check using Get-Culture; my locale is nb-NO (Norwegian) )

Consider this:

```
Get-Date
```

returns

```
tirsdag 23. mai 2017 13.13.18
```

So I do this

```
Get-Date -Format "H-m-s"
```

as expected it returns

```
13-13-18
```

But then I do this

```
Get-Date -Format "H:m:s"
```

You think it returns

```
13:13:18
```

right? (it does on PS5.0!) No! I get this:

```
13.13.18
```

Only if I do this, is the output what I want:

```
Get-Date -Format "H\:m\:s"
13:13:18
```

Can someone please explain why this is? I discovered it "by accident" when I wanted to format a datetime-compatible string for use in SQL Server.

Comment: I'd simply use `Get-Date -Format "T"`

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't solve anything, it still returns as 13.13.18 for me.

Comment: Well not everyone knows the time separator from nb-NO out of the head, so precede my above command with  @Mathias tip `[CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.TimeSeparator = ":"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the underlying `DateTime` formatting function see's `:` and treats it as a [culture-dependent "time separator"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.timeseparator.aspx).

In Norwegian (`no-NO`), the default time separator is `.`. You can inspect this with (assuming that `no-NO` is the current culture):

```
PS C:\> [CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.TimeSeparator
.
```

You can also override this, either by inserting a literal `:`, with the escape sequence `\:` as you've already found, or you can override it globally (for the lifetime of the current process/appdomain):

```
PS C:\> [CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.TimeSeparator = ":"
PS C:\> Get-Date -Format "H:m:s"
13:13:18
```

Comment: Thanks! The literal ":" doesn't do it for me, but using the escape sequence does. Also, why has this changed since PS 5.0?

Comment: Sorry, was being unclear - if you want a literal `:` in the resulting string, you *need* to use the escape sequence. AFAIK, it's not because of any changes in PowerShell, but because of the underlying DateTime formatting implementation differing between .NET 3.5 (CLR 2.0) and .NET 4.5 (CLR 4.0), no idea why